# understanding detab in K&R

Tags: c, tabs, modulo, kernighan-and-ritchie, entab-detab

I'm teaching myself C and working through K&R.  I'm doing exercise 1-20:

> Write a Program entab that replaces strings of blanks by the minimum number of tabs and blanks to acheive the same spacing. Use the same tab stops as for detab.

I worked through this program myself, but was reviewing other solutions:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define TABINC 8

int main(void)
{
  int nb,pos,c;

  nb = 0;
  pos = 1;

  while((c=getchar())!=EOF)
  {
    if( c == '\t')
    {
      nb = TABINC - (( pos - 1) % TABINC);   // <---- How does this work

      while( nb > 0)
      {
        putchar('#');
        ++pos;
        --nb;
      }
    }
    else if( c == '\n')
    {
      putchar(c);
      pos = 1;
    }
    else
    {
      putchar(c);
      ++pos;
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I have difficulty understanding how this part works `nb = TABINC - (( pos - 1) % TABINC);`.  Can someone please explain what this is exactly doing step by step? Perhaps walk me through an example?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the following input text:

```
\tone\ntwo\tthree\nsixteen\tseventeen\teighteen\n
```

This is what we want it to produce (tabs replaced with `···`):

```
         Column: |       |       |       |
         123456789012345678901234567890123
Line: 1  ········one
      2  two·····three
      3  sixteen·seventeen·······eighteen
```

The number of spaces required for each tab character is always going to be a number from 1 to `TABINC` (i.e., 8) inclusive. The tabs in the above example are expanded as follows:

```
Current   Next tab   No. spaces
column#   position   required
   1          9         8
   4          9         5
   8          9         1
  18         25         7
```

You should be able to see a pattern here. If we are already at a tab position (1, 9, 17, etc.), we need to add 8 spaces. And in general, if we are `n` characters past a tab position (where `0 <= n <= 7`), then we need to add `8-n` spaces.

We can calculate `n` easily:

```
n = (pos - 1) % 8
```

so `nb` (the number of spaces we need to add) can simply be calculated as follows:

```
nb = 8 - n
```

Hence

```
nb = 8 - ((pos - 1) % 8)
```

Or, more generally,

```
nb = TABINC - ((pos - 1) % TABINC)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for explanation given by r3mainer
Here gives my shorter version

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define TABW 8

int main()
{
    int c, pos;

    pos = 1;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (c == '\n') {
            pos = 1;
            putchar(c);
        }
        else if (c == '\t') {
            for (int ns = TABW - ((pos - 1) % TABW); ns > 0; --ns) {
                ++pos;
                putchar(' ');
            }
        }
        else {
            ++pos;
            putchar(c);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```